# Pass mehod to task from Form1 class

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

i have a program that send method and its arguments to another Task from Form1 class(Windows Form-UI) .

i wrote :

```
private void Activate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Task task = new Task(() => mng.start(switchAB.Text, switchC.Text, switchDE.Text, switchF.Text, switchG.Text, switchH.Text,textBox1.Text));
     task.Start();
}
```

but i having the error :

> invalidoperationexception was unhandled by user code -

Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'switchAB' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

mng.start is a method that get this arguments at managet class .

how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

I think the error tells you every thing you need to know. You can't access UI elements from a thread other than the thread it was created on. So when you access `switchAB.Text` inside the task you violate this rule.

The trick is to get the text on the UI thread and just pass it as text into the task.

Try this:

```
private void Activate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sab = switchAB.Text;
    var sc = switchC.Text;
    var sde = switchDE.Text;
    var sf = switchF.Text;
    var sg = switchG.Text;
    var sh = switchH.Text;
    var tb1 = textBox1.Text;
    Task task = new Task(() => mng.start(sab, sc, sde, sf, sg, sh, tb1));
    task.Start();
}
```